# Manually triggering "Done" on the iOS Safari Form Accessory Bar

Tags: ios, cordova, select, safari

How do you manually trigger the "Done" (submit) button from the form accessory bar in iOS Safari?

You can call the blur() method on the active input/select HTML element, but that does not result in the same behavior.

Problem: The HTML select element shows a UIPickerView in iOS Safari. I'm running a hybrid app where there is no form accessory bar (it's been set to hidden in the WKWebView config). If i call blur(), the select element will discard my selection. I simply want it to remember whatever was chosen in the UIPickerView and trigger an change event like it normally would if I tapped on "Done" in the form accessory bar.

Anyone?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question completely, because usually the iOS "Done" button only hides the keyboard, and does not submit anything. However, you can listen to the event of (cordova Keyboard plugin) Keyboard.onhide to catch a similar event. Perhaps this has the desired effect for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I did try that as well actually. In the case of input elements, just listening for the onhide or blur elements is fine, but when it comes to the HTML Select element, it would Seem like (just a theory) that the Done Button acts like some kind of bridge between the native UIPickerView selection and the webview. Anyway, I decided to build my own custom picker as a last resort which actually works great.